# Is there a way to get the latest TypeScript version supported by `typescript-eslint` programmatically?

Tags: typescript-eslint

I want to update TypeScript to its latest version supported by `typescript-eslint`.

I tried to use `pnpm info typescript-eslint`, however, the output either does not include `typescript` or it is set to support all (`*`) TS versions.

```js
// pnpm info typescript-eslint peerDependencies
{ eslint: '^8.56.0' }

// pnpm info typescript-eslint devDependencies
{
  'downlevel-dts': '*',
  jest: '29.7.0',
  prettier: '^3.0.3',
  rimraf: '*',
  typescript: '*'
}

// pnpm info typescript-eslint dependencies
{
  '@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin': '7.1.1',
  '@typescript-eslint/parser': '7.1.1'
}
```

The only way I could find is to get it from the docs which is not the best way. I could not find any file in their repository which could be used for this purpose.

```bash
pnpm i "typescript@$(
  curl -s https://typescript-eslint.io/users/dependency-versions/ | \
    grep -Po 'The version range of TypeScript currently supported is.*<code>\K.*(?=</code>)' | \
    sed 's/&gt;/>/;s/&lt;/</g'
)"
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this in the [root-level `package.json` in the typescript-eslint repository](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/package.json), under `peerDependencies`. As of posting (typescript-eslint@7), that's `"typescript": ">=4.7.4 <5.4.0"`.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/2960201c31b7acf35e747db0bf4b8d2064223f04/package.json#L121

Comment: Thanks. This is a better answer. The actual command that could be used is as follows: `curl -Ls "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/releases/latest | jq -r .tag_name)/package.json" | jq -r .devDependencies.typescript`.